# rewrite dynamic url with form submit

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a dynamic url coming from submit form:

this is the code of form submit:

the correspond url is: mondomain/search.php?id_ac=23

i want to rewrite this to mondomain/23

any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?id_ac=([^&]+)&id_de=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?id_ac=$1&id_de=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thank you, but how can i change the code of form action + page php?

Comment: DIdn't understand your comment, can you clarify a bit.

Comment: my current form code is: form action="search.php" method="get"><select name=id_ac><option...</option></select> how can i change this with a new url rewriting

Comment: You don't need to change that form code. Once form is submitted to `/search.php?id_ac=23` URI it will be redirected to `/23` by these rules.

Comment: if i have 2 parameters, /search.php?id_ac=23&id_de=12 how can i put  RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L] ? thanks in advance

Comment: But in the question you didn't mention about 2nd parameter. Anyway what pretty URL you need for these 2 parameters?

Comment: i want to add an other parameter like this:                       <form action="search.php" method="get"><select name=id_ac><option...</option></select><select name=id_de><option...</option></select> </form>   url: mondomain/23-12

Comment: Right understood but how will pretty URL look like e.g. `mondomain/23-"foo"` where `foo is id_ac`.

Comment: no, now i have a current url like this domain/search.php?id_ac=23&id_de=12 i want to rewrite this to domain/23-12

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: not work, i  get not the result of research, I'm still on the same page ;(

Comment: This is full tested rule. `/search.php?id_ac=23&id_de=12` redirects to `/23-12` most likely you haven't placed this in DocumentRoot/.htaccess

Comment: Then are you sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled? Contact your admin to get this resolve.

Comment: yes, i did rewrite urls of my website but , i didn't rewrite url of form submitting (GET)

Comment: When you enter `http://example.com/search.php?id_ac=23&id_de=12` what does it change to?

Comment: when I click a search button the url becomes http://example.com/23-12 but it gives no result as when I enter the url http://example.com/search . php? id_ac = 23 = 12 & id_de

Comment: http://example.com/search.php?id_ac=23&id_de=12 it change to http://example.com/23-12 but no result

Comment: So if you directly enter: `example.com/23-12` you don't see any content? Run that URL in firebug and see what you get in Net tab.

Comment: same problem, i m still on the same page

Comment: There were 2 parts in my previous comment. Did you do the firebug part?

Comment: And then what? Where are the details? Why do I have to ask same question 3 times?

Comment: Sorry, when i enter the url in firebug, i show GET search.php?id_ac=23&id_de=12 (302 found) and under this i show GET 23-12 (200 OK) ..

Comment: Ok that's good then it is not a 404. You are getting 200 for `/23-12` URI and content from `/search.php?id_ac=32&id_de=12` will be shown.

Comment: Comment out first 2 lines from above rule and then open `http://domain.com/search.php?id_ac=32&id_de=12` in a new browser.

Comment: when i commented this: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?id_ac=([^&]+)&id_de=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2? [R=302,L], i get the result of  http://domain.com/search.php?id_ac=32&id_de=12 as url. and same as enter http://domain.com/search.php?id_ac=32&id_de=12 in the new browser.

Comment: thank you anubhava 
it work perfectly now, i have added a location of actual page in search.php